# on demand resources for fonts in Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Can we fetch font file .otf and .ttf files on demand in Xamarin ios?  Below is the sample code to fetch the fonts in swift asynchronously. I'm looking for the same in C#.

```
{
 (void)asynchronouslySetFontName:(NSString *)fontName toTextView:(UITextView *)textView {
        CGFloat size = 24.0f;
        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
    
        if (font && ([font.fontName compare:fontName] == NSOrderedSame || [font.familyName compare:fontName] == NSOrderedSame)) {
            textView.font = font;
            return;
        }
    
        NSMutableDictionary *attrs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fontName forKey:kCTFontNameAttribute];
        CTFontDescriptorRef desc = CTFontDescriptorCreateWithAttributes((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attrs);
    
        NSMutableArray *descs = [NSMutableArray array];
        [descs addObject:(__bridge id)desc];
        CFRelease(desc);
    
        __weak UITextView *weakTextView = textView;
    
        CTFontDescriptorMatchFontDescriptorsWithProgressHandler((__bridge CFArrayRef)descs, NULL,  ^(CTFontDescriptorMatchingState state, CFDictionaryRef progressParameter) {
    
            if (state == kCTFontDescriptorMatchingDidFinish) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    weakTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:size];
                });
            }
    
            return YES;
        });
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to convert same code to Xamarin iOS c#? Is this feature compatible with Xamarin?

Comment: Fetch from where? Bundle resources or internet?

Comment: I'm looking for an option to reduce the app size as the font files in the current apps are making the app huge. So we can also opt for the option to use on demand resource tag for those font files or use above code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce the size of the application, you could try download fonts and install them at runtime. There is a similar issue on Github issue which you could refer to:
[load fonts from web on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493815/load-fonts-from-web-on-demand). The accepted answer using [Xamarin.Forms DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to register Fonts at iOS runtime. But first you should download and put fonts file to [Cache directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#application-directories)  .

Hope it works for you.